# Where could I get the EER Diagram of stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, data-dump

I would like to know if it is possibe or avaliable the stackexchange sites database model.

If yes, where could I get it?

Comment: Related, cross site Q&A: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the schema for the data dump and [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) in [**this Meta Stack Exchange post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

The architecture of the production database is not available to non-corporate customers (if it's available at all).  But, you can grab one of the public domain [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones); their schema is no-doubt similar.